# Computer completely freezes randomly

Tags: windows, freeze

Ever since I got a new motherboard since my other one was having issues, my PC has had a tendency to just completely freeze up on me out of the blue. The cursor doesn't move anymore, the screen is stuck on the same frame, the sound from my headphones completely comes to a halt and the fans continue to spin at a constant speed.
At the time when I got my new motherboard, I also got a new PSU, CPU and m.2 SSD so I am not entirely certain what causes the issue.
This has been going on for a long time, but at times it would only do it every so often for a couple days and then function normally for the coming weeks, but recently it got extremely bad to the point where it often just consistently halts right after logging in, or even on the main login screen or during boot (which obviously is bad as the only fix is to hard reset it).

I am honestly out of ideas of what it could possibly be and would love some input.

I am running Windows 11 22000.184 (although the problem also occurred on Windows 10).
My motherboard is a Gigabyte Z390 Gaming X, my CPU is an Intel Core I9-9900kf and my PSU is a Corsair RM850.
The SSD is a Seagate BarraCuda Q5 2tb and I also have an RTX 3060 Ti, 3 1tb HDDs that are quite of age and Corsair Vengeance 32gb 3600Mhz RAM.

If anyone even has a clue as to what may be causing this, I'm happy to hear you out.

Comment: Based on your description it sounds like a HW issue. Does the PSU give enough power to run all your hardware simultaneously? If yes, I'd start by disconnecting all drives except for the OS installation drive and one of the RAM modules, and testing. If that works, swap the RAM and test again. If it still works, add the second one back and test. If it's still working start adding rest of the drives and other peripherals, always one by one, and test one at the time till you find the point of failure. As a side note; Win11 is still under development so it can be expected to behave weirdly.

Comment: This seems to me like a grounding issue. Did you build this system yourself? Do you use a UPS or a regulator? Also as Peregrino said is your PSU capable to run all that hardware?

Comment: My PSU is 850 watts which should be plenty to support all my hardware and yes, I did build my pc myself, @human_rrosas.

Comment: Just to be sure here. Did you use the mounting posts for your motherboard that go between this last one and the case

Comment: temperature issue? mounting cpu cooler with thermal paste is not everyone's task. dust may block cooler ribs

Comment: I recently cleaned my radiator that's used to cool the CPU, so unless the AIO cooler isn't working, I doubt temperature is the issue.

Comment: are you planning to watch CPU temperature / voltages / current with some tool like Core Temp, CPU-Z, CPUID HWMonitor, TechPowerup GPUTool, Everest or Speedfan, or do we persist on guesswork only?

Comment: Since I posted this issue, my PC has not been acting up as described. The issue will undoubtedly return later as it has done for many months and when it does, I will be posting here. Until that day, however, I suppose we must let it rest.
P.s. I recently upgraded my PSU from a 650 watt to an 850 watt one and in both cases, the issue arose, so I am certain that power is not the issue.